# Linux/64-bit /LARGEADDRESSAWARE equivalent

Tags: linux, gcc, 64-bit, porting, large-address-aware

Windows enables you to restrict address-space usage to a 32-bit resolution by setting a flag in the PE header (`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`). To elaborate: When set, this flag effectively emulates a 32-bit virtual address space environment (image is loaded at/allocations return- addresses <= 0xFFFFFFFF)

Does Linux have an equivalent feature?

Comment: Is there some specific requirement for this, or is an academic inquiry?

Comment: Porting software that makes makes -alot- of assumptions about pointers being 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocating memory in 32-bit space on x86-64 can be done by performing [`mmap(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) with the `MAP_32BIT` flag.

Comment: What about the issue of the load address? Particularly in respect to shared libraries.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do about that. You'll probably have to copy memory contents around.

Answer (score 0):

`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` allows an extended address space from 2 to 4 gigabytes for 32-bit Windows applications. Otherwise, a 32-bit application on Windows cannot reach those addresses.
Linux from early on could reach them, so a `/LARGEADRSSAWARE` link flag is not needed.

Comment: In a 32-bit PE, yes. 64-bit PEs use it differently.